# Jquery autocomplete does not always work

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i've been using this code to `autocomplete` the `input`. In many cases the code works fine, but in some it doesn't. It relates `iOS` User, `Android` User, `Windows 7, 8, 10` User, `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

AvailabeTags includes 13500 listings.

Thanks for your help ;)

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 3,
  delay: 100,
  autoFocus: false,
  source: function (request, response) {
  var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term)
            , startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
            , startsWith = $.grep(availableTags, function(value) {
                return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            })
            , containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i")
            , contains = $.grep(availableTags, function (value) {
                return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 &&
                    containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            });

        response(startsWith.concat(contains));
    },
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $( "#tags" ).val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $( "#{/literal}{$plzid}{literal}" ).val(ui.item.plz);
    $( "#{/literal}{$blid}{literal}" ).val(ui.item.bl);
    return false;
  }                       
   });
```

Comment: any console errors when this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

i think better you can use php to handle datas to be displayed in the inout field

php code:

search.php

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$key = $_GET["term"];
$query = "select * from students where name like '%$key%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($ser=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = $ser["name"];
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

jquery Code here:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#name").autocomplete({
  source:'search.php'
  });
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="name">
```

Note:
Dont't forgot to add the Jquery UI plugin